# Why use a star or delta connection instead of having a second output

Tags: current, ac, three-phase, alternator, delta

I am winding my own small three phase ac alternator and have learned about star and delta connections. Should I use 2 three phase rectifiers to turn the current to DC or only one with a star connection on the other end?
EDIT: To be more clear, there are 3 sets of wires which current will be induced to. Most alternators take the first end of each set of wires to make a 3 phase current, but take the other ends of the wires to make either a star or delta connection. Why not just have another three phase output for twice the power output? Note I am also using rectifiers to change the AC current to a DC current (I am using a three phase alternator so the output of the full wave rectifier will be smoother).

Comment: Star or delta only needs 1 rectifier of 6 diodes (9 diodes including the w/l connection) - well for all the vehicle / car / truck alternators I worked on .

Comment: @Luke: Use 2 x <Enter> for paragraph breaks. There's a question mark on the right of the toolbar which opens up the markup syntax help.

Answer (score 1):

**Delta is generally preferred** as it gives higher voltage, lower currents and conduction losses. This requires 2 diodes per phase as there is no Neutral return.  ( 6 diodes for 3 phase )

Star (or Y or wye) config is preferred;

- when the voltage is too high for the added cost of insulation required but needs only 1 diode per phase and neutral.
- Alternatively, it  is used when when the higher current is desired for maximum power transfer when impedances are closed to being matched.